# json jq formatting unnamed objects onto single line

Tags: json, jq

Another question re 'jq' formatting onto a single line.   Here is my json file:

```
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "title":[
        "primary",5981,
        "database",5965,
        "source",5963,
        "eecm",5949,
        "the",5066,
        "research",4888]},
    "facet_ranges":{}
  }
}
```

As you see there is no label assigned for the tuplets within the title array.  I want to print the output like: -

```
        "primary",5981,
        "database",5965,
        "source",5963,
        "eecm",5949,
        "the",5066,
        "research",4888
```

So far, I've been trying **jq -c '.facet_counts.facet_fields.title[]'**, but members of the tuplet are being output on different lines (i.e. effectively decoupled): -

```
"primary"
5981
"database"
5965
"source"
5963
"eecm"
5949
"the"
5066
"research"
4888
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the array into chunks with `_nwise`, then `join()` those with a char of your liking:

```
.facet_counts.facet_fields.title | _nwise(2) | join(": ")
```

```
primary: 5981
database: 5965
source: 5963
eecm: 5949
the: 5066
research: 4888
```

---

###### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4fI4NpFnnxp)

Comment: Using `_nwise(2) | first |= @json | …` would also add the JSON formatting (quotes) to the strings on the left side, if needed.

Comment: Interesting solution. `_nwise` is undocumented. See it at https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/71c2ab509a8628dbbad4bc7b3f98a64aa90d3297/src/builtin.jq#L102

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe the output of `jq` to format it:

```
jq ... | paste -d, - -
```